# Repeating, rotating background images on mouseover

Tags: css

I would like to create a background pattern that is slightly animated. The idea: small crosses that rotate on mouseover. Each repeating cross should rotate on mouseover and rotate back on mouseout.

I have tried the following solution. However, the whole background is rotated, but not the individual elements.

```
.el-section {
    background-image: url("/Untitled-2.svg");
    background-size: 50px 50px;
    background-repeat: repeat;
}

.el-section:hover {
    cursor: default;
    transform: rotate(360deg);
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}
```

Comment: please include [mcve]

Comment: we dont know what "whole section" or "individual elements" are, and the code you provided is minimal

Comment: as no code is given, it can be speculated that the css properties are being applied to the whole section instead of children

Comment: The whole background rotates because the background is seen as a single element. To do what I think you're asking, each cross would need to be a separate element. The only other option I could think of would require using a large canvas as a background layer with some javascript.

Comment: Can you clarify the effect you are seeking? Is it just one cross to rotate at a time? What is to happen as the cursor moves across between crosses?

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this without having hundreds of individual elements would be to use a repeating background as you have done and then the before and after pseudo elementof the section become the cross that will be rotated.

This keeps the JS fairly minimal too.

Here's a simple example.

Remember that in a real life example you will probably need to account for the position of any container - in this snippet it's just the window.

```html
<style>
  * {
    margin: 0;
  }
  
  .el-section {
    --bg: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/wpI4c.png);
    background-image: var(--bg);
    background-size: 50px 50px;
    background-repeat: repeat;
    position: relative;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
  }
  
  .el-section::before,
  .el-section::after {
    content: '';
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-size: 50px 50px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: absolute;
    top: var(--top);
    left: var(--left);
    cursor: default;
  }
  
  .el-section::before {
    background-image: linear-gradient(white, white);
    z-index: 1;
  }
  
  .el-section::after {
    background-image: var(--bg);
    animation: var(--name) 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
    z-index: 2;
  }
  
  @keyframes rot {
    to {
      transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
  }
</style>
<div class="el-section"></div>
<script>
  const elSection = document.querySelector('.el-section');
  elSection.addEventListener('mousemove', function() {
    elSection.style.setProperty('--left', Math.floor(event.pageX / 50) * 50 + 'px');
    elSection.style.setProperty('--top', Math.floor(event.pageY / 50) * 50 + 'px');
    elSection.style.setProperty('--name', 'rot');
  });

  function removeAnimation() {
    elSection.style.setProperty('--name', '');
  }

  elSection.addEventListener('animationend', removeAnimation);
</script>
```